# In SPSS, is there a statistical test to compare contribution (totals) from three categories

Tags: categorical-data, spss

I am analysing sales data for products separated into three categories. Each product can exist in only one category, and there is an estimated percentage of products in each category such that:

```
A: ~50% of products
B: ~30% of products
C: ~20% of products
```

My hypothesis is that despite that fact that C has less than 20% of products, it makes up a significant portion of the revenue (especially when compared to A). For the sake of my analysis, I want to assume that each product is roughly the same price.

I used a Chi-square to determine if there was a significant difference in the NUMBER of products from each category (there was, P < 0.01). The actual distribution of products ends up being like this:

```
A: n=56, ~24%
B: n=64, ~27%
C: n=116, ~49%
```

When I look at my revenue, by category, I have something like this:

```
A: 72,000 (~15%) - was expecting ~50%
B: 160,000 (~34%) - was expecting ~30%
C: 233,000 (~50%) - was expecting ~20%
```

Logically, I can see that the amount of revenue generated from category C is bigger than expected (20%) but it also matches the proportion of the products (i.e. 50% of the products were from category C, so it makes sense that 50% of the revenue comes from this category). What I want to to determine is whether or not the variance of +30% sales is significant compared to the -35% sales from category A compared to what we expect, similar to what I have done with the Chi-Square.

When I compare Means (using One-way ANOVA), there is no significant difference between groups (and, in-fact, the mean of category B is higher than C), but I think that is because of the fact that I haven't "told" the test what proportion I expect from each group.

Is there another way I can compare these groups to see if there is a difference in percentages?

Comment: Cannot be answered without knowing the number of products in each category. For example, if I have a result that 100% of the flips of a coin are heads, that doesn't mean much at all if I only flipped the coin once. But if I flipped the coin 1000 times and got 100% heads, I would likely be looking at a two-headed coin.

Comment: I have edited the question to include the number of products in each category, as well as some additional analysis.